# document.querySelector('body').insertAdjacentHTML. Какая противоположность?

Tags: javascript

document.querySelector('body').ejectAdjacentHTML не работает.

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, в каком моменте не работает, какая такая "противоположность", что вы пытались сделать и что у вас не получилось?

Comment: `insertAdjacentHTML` — позволяет вставлять произвольный HTML в любое место документа, в том числе и между узлами. Что по-вашему есть противоположность вставки html в любое место документа?

Comment: как убрать document.querySelector('body').insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: а как это убрать?

Answer (score 1):

Никакой. Работай с dom-элементами. Всякие там `remove` и `removeChild`.